# How is the skillset of an evolution being chosen?

Tags: pokemon-go

You may already know that if you catch two Pidgeys, they may have a different skillset.

I've also seen that evolving them from different skillsets will also create Pidgeottos with different skillsets.

**Are those skills chosen randomly or do they follow a specific pattern?** (Like Pidgey pattern 1 will always evolve into Pidgeotto pattern 1.)

If they are specific, is there a website to check for them?

Comment: Very interesting question. I will be evolving a few Pokemon probably tonight and will write down my results to see.

Comment: That'd be cool! Unfortunatelly I live in rural area (not enough players around) so I can't test it myself in a reasonable time.

Comment: Exactly what I came here to ask, I hope experiments lead to good results

Comment: http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon.shtml list of abilities, hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Honestly, it just seems to be random.

Answer (score 9):

I found a reddit post that lists special moves but the top comment asks about move correlation: https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4sqqb0/movesmovesets_in_pokemon_go_an_almost_complete/

One of the comments provided a chart that illustrates the moves a pidgey learns when evolved into a pidgeotto: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9fJW.png

It shows that there is no 100% correlation at all between movesets from one evolution to another. If there is a ratio at all between moves I cannot say for sure due to the small sample size given.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying trial and error and it's really hard to tell how to get the best move sets I'm not for sure if it's random but I have seen that I get the best attack skills from evolving XS Pokémon

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing that part, and all I can tell you is it's random. Yesterday I evolved a Pidgey->Pidgeotto and got same skillset. And few days ago, I evolved 3 Rattata; 3 of them got 2 new skills, the other got the same skillset.

Answer (score -1):

They follow a pattern. Each Pokemon has two possible normal moves and three possible specials. When a Pokemon evolves, the evolution will end up with the moves in the same 'slots' as the original. For example, a Rattata which knows Tackle will always evolve into a Raticate which knows Bite.

Comment: May I have some source to that?

Answer (score -3):

It SHOULD keep the same move-set as the pre-evolution, with 1 to 2 new attacks, maybe even forgetting a move. I do know their still different, since I evolved 2, but its all chance based.

Comment: Are you talking about Pokemon GO, or a different Pokemon game? Pokemon in Pokemon GO only have 2 moves total, and both can change when evolving.