# Evolve ekans with higher CP or higher HP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have below two ekans.
1. CP 177 , **HP 28/28**,  weight 9.28, poison:acid:10, poison:GunkShot:60
2. CP 170 , **HP 31/31**,  weight 9.12, poison:poisonSting:6, poison:SludgeBomb:50

Basically second one has higher HP and poison type is different. I have 50 candy to evolve one of it. Which one do you suggest to evolve and why? does after evolve CP/HP be different? Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evolving Pokemon based on CP vs Moves](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274764/evolving-pokemon-based-on-cp-vs-moves)

Comment: @Frank I disagree. This is about IVs too.

Comment: @Studoku Huh?  How is this about IVs?  There's no mention of IVs anywhere in the question.

Comment: A pokemon's stats depend on its level and IV. If you want the best Arbok in the long run, you'll need to calculate its IVs using an online calculator. To do this, you'll need its CP, HP, and power up cost.

Comment: @Frank IVs are why one has higher HP, so it's about that even if OP doesn't realise. At any rate, the other question makes no mention of HP.

Comment: @Studoku Sounds like a good answer to the other question would cover all of that.

Comment: I agree with studoku. Answer in other thread is totally based on CP. So my HP does not even matter when evolving?

Comment: @Akie Actually the opposite. It matters allows you to calculate the IVs and fully levelled potential of the pokemon. https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator

Answer (score 0):

do not evolve any. wait to have higher trainer level so you will find higher CP ekans.