# Question about Evolving pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

Salutations.

I have a question about evolving certain pokemon. I have a Golbat with a CP of 242 and has two sets of attack with (10,15) power respectively. I also have another Zubat with CP of 105 but with a attack set of (10,25). Which one should I evolve? I am confused between whether to prioritize attack sets or CP for evolution. Thank you!

Comment: Wait is the 242 a Golbat or a Zubat, in this game Crobat is unavailable since only Gen 1 Pokemon are present

Comment: 242 CP is a Golbat with a move set with power of (10,15)
and 105 CP is a Zubat with a move set with power of (10,25)

Comment: Also related: [How is the skillset of an evolution being chosen?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273494/how-is-the-skillset-of-an-evolution-being-chosen)

Comment: As @IG_42 mentioned, you can't evolve Golbat. Are you asking which one to keep (i.e. should you get rid of the Golbat and evolve the Zubat instead)?

Answer (score 0):

- You can't evolve Golbat because that is currently its final evolution in this game.
- The attack sets of pokemon change when they evolve, so it doesn't matter what Zubat has.
- CP isn't always the best indicator when comparing two *different* types of pokemon. Instead, you should go by how much of the bar above their head is filled. This bar gives a general indication of the pokemon's current level, and the higher the better, because that means less stardust has to be spent to power them up.
- If I had to guess, Zubat is probably a higher level than your Golbat, despite having lower CP. That Zubat would probably evolve into a 310-365 CP Golbat.